# Something wrong with cPanel website.

Tags: php, cpanel

I uploaded my website yesterday and everything was fine. I made some changes today and a lot seems to have been broken. For example

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['u_email'])){
    header("Location: home.php");}
```

no longer works. I can view the webpage as someone with no account. Although other code that requires log in works fine. Even just

```
header("Location: home.php");
```

at the start doesn't redirect. And I have the correct .htaccess. I also made a complete copy of my files and it ran fine on a local server.

Also I can't get this to work on either servers.

```
<? if(isset($_SESSION['u_email'])){
    echo '<p>
           <form class="fav" action="includes/favourite.inc.php?img_id=<?=$images[0]->img_id?>" method="POST">
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Add to gallery</button>
            </form>
          <p>';}?>
```

I've spent a long time trying to figure it out so I appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you short tags enable in `php.ini`?Because you're using `<?`.Try edit it with `<?php...?>`

Comment: they are enabled but I tried <?php anyway and still no luck

Comment: Try this:`<?php if(isset($_SESSION['u_email'])){
?>
    <p>
           <form class="fav" action="includes/favourite.inc.php?img_id=<? $images[0]->img_id ?> method="POST">
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Add to gallery</button>
            </form>
          <p>
<?php
}?>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't Started Session

add the session start top of your pages

```
session_start();
```

and if it not works check your server php.ini whether session variables are set..
look for php short tags, http session secure.. etc.